# When using Django's Default Storage should/can you close() an opened file?

Tags: django

When using Django's `DefaultStorage` it's possible to open and read a file something like this:

```py
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

file = default_storage.open("dir/file.txt", mode="rb")
data = file.read()
```

When using python's own `open()` method, it's best to `close()` the file afterwards, or use a `with open("dir/file.txt") as file:` construction.

But reading [the docs for Django's Storage classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/storage/), and browsing [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/files/storage.py), I don't see a `close()` equivalent.

So my questions are:

1. Should a file opened with Django's Default Storage be closed?
2. If so, how?
3. If not, why isn't it necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't see a close method because you are looking at the `Storage` class. The `open` method of the `Storage` class returns an instance of [`django.core.files.base.File` [Source code]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ec212c66167759a2a40b13d5efc47d883816d4da/django/core/files/base.py#L8) which basically wraps the python file object and also has a `close` method that closes the file (The methods like `read`, etc. are inherited from `FileProxyMixin`).

Generally when you open a file you *should* close it, this is the same with Django, which is also emphasised in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#the-file-object):

> Closing files is especially important when accessing file fields in a
> loop over a large number of objects. If files are not manually closed
> after accessing them, the risk of running out of file descriptors may
> arise. This may lead to the following error:
>
> ```
> OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
> ```

But there are few instances where you shouldn't close files, which mostly are when you are passing the file to some function / method / object that will read it, for example if you create a [`FileResponse` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) you shouldn't close the file as Django will close it by itself:

> The file will be closed automatically, so don’t open it with a context
> manager.

To complete your example code, you will close the file as:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

file = default_storage.open("dir/file.txt", mode="rb")
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I should have guessed (and tried) to just do `file.close()` but I got confused by looking for a `close()` method in the Django Storage docs and not seeing it. Now I know why.